# \textbf does not work insine \newcommand

Tags: macros

I'm trying to make a new command, to add autoincrementing numbers to the definitions throughout my thesis. Here's what I have.

```
\newcounter{DefCounter}
\setcounter{DefCounter}{0}

\newcommand{\mydefinition}[1]{
    \stepcounter{DefCounter}
    \textbf{Определение \theDefCounter.}#1
}
```

When I use it like this: `\mydefinition{DEFINITION BODY}` I get the numbering right, but the `Определение 1.` text is not bold.
What should I change to make this text bold?

Comment: I can't replicate the result. Can you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the result?

Comment: It's likely that the font you're using doesn't support have bold face.  Are you able to have bold text with, say, `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\textbf{hello, world}\end{document}`?

Comment: @SeanAllred thanks a lot. That is the problem indeed, I will have to modify the template I'm using. Wish I had the common sence to check if \textbf works in my case.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) we all make this kind of mistake now and again (and again, and again, and again, …) That said, I think this is rather a duplicate of another question somewhere. This is a pretty common problem, but usually when people try to combine bold and small caps styles in the default font.

Comment: By the way, if you are using LaTeX counter, consider printing a counter in LaTeX flavor. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the template I'm using. The font defined in it does not support \textbf. The problem has nothing to do with macros.
UPD. Silly me. The template was ok, I just had to install the font.